# Custom monolog handler for default monolog in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

I want to add a custom handler to a default monolog in [Symfony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symfony) 2.

In my `config.yaml` file, I have:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:  stream
            path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
            level: debug
        myHandler:
            type:  Acme\MyBundle\Monolog\MyCustomHandler
            level: error
```

My class looks like below:

```
// Acme\MyBundle\Monolog\MyCustomHandler
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\SocketHandler;
use Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter;

class MyCustomHandler extends AbstractProcessingHandler
{
    ...
}
```

But even before I fill my class in I get an error:

> invalid handler type "acme\mybundle\monolog\mycustomhandler" given for handler "myHandler"

How do I add a custom handler to the default monolog without creating a new monolog service?

Comment: Why don't you want to create a service?

Comment: Just an example for future readers about this very old and useful question: Fully working example is here: http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/53en/storing-symfony-log-messages-in-database-with-custom-monolog-handler

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try this:

```yml
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:  stream
            path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
            level: debug
        custom:
            type: service
            id: my_custom_handler

services:
    my_custom_handler:
        class: Acme\MyBundle\Monolog\MyCustomHandler
```

If you want to use it as default handler then you should change a bit monolog section I wrote above.

```yml
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:  stream
            path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
            level: debug
            handler: custom
        custom:
            type: service
            id: my_custom_handler
```

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 8):

I just found out that `Monolog` ships with a set of various handlers so you might wanna use one of those instead of writing your own. I am using the `LogEntriesHandler` for logging to logentries.com but there are a few more as documented here: https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog#log-specific-servers-and-networked-logging

My Symfony2 config for that looks like that:

```
monolog:
    main:
        type:  fingers_crossed
        level: debug
        handler: nested
    custom:
        type: service
        id: monolog.handler.logentries
        level: error

services:
    monolog.handler.logentries:
        class: Monolog\Handler\LogEntriesHandler
        arguments:
            token: %logentries_token%
```