# Symfony 2 - Don't pass logging to next handler

Tags: symfony, monolog

I've defined a service to handle logging of records with specific text (e.g. "matched route" and such).  I'm successfully writing those records out to a separate file.

However, what I want to avoid is writing them a second time to the primary log file.  I've tried tagging my service with a channel and telling the main stream log to ignore that channel, but it occurs to me that it won't work since, in essence, the main stream logging handler matches *everything*.

Any advice on how to proceed?

EDIT: Here's what I have at the moment:

```
monolog:
    channels: ['noise']
    handlers:
        eliminate_noise_logger:
            type: service
            id: common.eliminate_noise_logger
            channels: ['noise']

        streamed:
            type:  stream
            level: info
            path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            formatter: monolog.formatter.session_request
            channels: ['!noise']

        console:
            type:  console
            verbosity_levels:
                VERBOSITY_NORMAL: INFO
```

And my services definition:

```
common.eliminate_noise_logger:
    class: path\to\class
    arguments: ["%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.noise.log", ["str1", "str2", "str3"]]
    tags:
        - { name: monolog.logger, channel: noise }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do

```
#config.yml
monolog:
    use_microseconds: false
    channels: ['secondary']
    handlers:
        main:
            path: %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.language%/%kernel.environment%.log
            type          : fingers_crossed
            action_level  : error
            handler       : nested
            channels      : ['!secondary']
        secondary:
            type: rotating_file
            max_files: 10
            path: %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.language%/%kernel.environment%.secondary.log
            level: info
            channels: [secondary]
```

Comment: I gave it a go, and it didn't work -- it's possible that I've got other things that are conflicting.  I can't recall exactly what the result was, but I know that the main log file continued to get the stuff I wanted filtered out.

Comment: Did you try with second handler named secondary (and not secondary_channel) ? It is a typo i just seen reviewing my answer

Comment: Think so.  I'm going to try again at some point in the next couple of days; work priorities shifted a bit.

Comment: Updated my question with the code I presently have.

Comment: If you want to use a service as handler you should have a look to http://stackoverflow.com/a/12937125/7169909.
Otherwise you can have a look to [MonologBundle configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/monolog.html)  on Symfony doc and [Monolog configuration](https://github.com/symfony/monolog-bundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php) on github. With the last link you will have minimum parameters to set for each handler type