# Sending messages to microsoft teams using Symfony Monolog

Tags: symfony, monolog

Alright so I am trying to send messages to Microsoft teams using Symfony Monolog, but  I cannot seem to find any sort of guides pointing how to do it or such.

I have tried doing it the same way as you would do it using Slack

I am using Symfony 3.4

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: critical
            handler:      mongo
#        nested:
#            type:  stream
#            path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
#            level: critical
        teams:
            type:  teams
            level: critical
            token: '%teams_token%'
            channel: '#errors'
            include_extra: true
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your [own Handler](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/doc/04-extending.md) like the [SlackHandler](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Handler/SlackHandler.php).

```
<?php

use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler;

class MicrosoftTeamsHandler extends AbstractProcessingHandler
{

...
```

Check this response [Custom monolog handler for default monolog in Symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935979/custom-monolog-handler-for-default-monolog-in-symfony-2) to register your custom handler and use it